# Sprite Kit - SKSpriteNode drawn at wrong position

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Whenever i try to draw a SKSpriteNode, it would be drawn lower than it should be.
But it seems that other SKSpriteNode works fine with no problems.

This is my current code:

```
func initMainGround() {
    let gSize = CGSizeMake(self.size.width/4*3, 120);
    ground = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.brownColor(), size: gSize);
    ground.name = gName;

    ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground.size);
    ground.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;
    ground.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
    ground.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.0;
    ground.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0;
    ground.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false;
    ground.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true; //accurate collision
    ground.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false;
    ground.physicsBody.dynamic = false;
    ground.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = gBitmask;
    ground.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = pBitmask;

    self.addChild(ground);
}

func addBomb() {
    let bomb = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "trap");
    bomb.size = CGSizeMake(30, 30);
    bomb.position = CGPointMake(ground.position.x, actualY+10);

    bomb.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bomb.size.width/2);
    bomb.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;
    bomb.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false;
    bomb.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true;
    bomb.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false;
    bomb.physicsBody.dynamic = false;
    bomb.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = bBitmask;
    bomb.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = pBitmask;
    bomb.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = pBitmask;

    self.addChild(bomb);
 }
```

Although the bomb is suppose to be almost directly above the ground, but it seems that the bomb is almost 100+ above the ground instead.
The ground is suppose to fill up almost one third of the screen height since the game is in landscape, but it is way lower than normal.

Why is it that the ground is drawn at the wrong position, but the bomb is drawn at the correct position?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the same problem I had when starting to work with SpriteKit. If your game uses an .sks file to present it's main scene (as it does by default), this scene uses arbitrary dimension values defined in the .sks file.

Try setting the dimensions of your scene dynamically to see if this is the case.
In your `didMoveToView` function, add something like this at the top of the function:

```
self.size = view.bounds.size
```

This way the dimension values from the .sks file will be overridden with your actual screen dimensions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have already changed the .sks file dimensions to the actual dimensions i needed, self.size.width also returns the correct width. so `self.size = view.bounds.size` did not really help here

Comment: This is a very awesome answer. I was banging my head against the wall as I had planned my entire app based on percentages for positions.

Comment: Thank you, sorted out my problem as well

Answer (score 2):

Set the anchorPoint on your ground image.

```
ground.anchorPoint = CGPointZero // same as CGPointMake(0, 0)
ground.position = CGPointZero
```

The default anchorPoint is (0.5, 0.5), the center of the image. So without it set, the center of the ground image is drawn in the lower left corner of the screen (0, 0).

Your bomb draws where you expect it for the same reason, the center is placed at the position you specified.